# In how many ways can six 3’s and four 2’s be arranged in a row so that the 2’s are always apart?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Need help solving this problem

My attempt:

There are 6 spots being taken by the 3's, so there are C(10,6) ways to arrange the

Answer (score 0):

Try it in another way:

Start by aligning **all** the 2s. You know they must be apart, so put one 3 between each one. Now you have this configuration: $2\ 3\ 2\ 3\ 2\ 3\ 2$

You still have three 3s to place. In how many ways can you place them?

Answer (score 0):

After the first 3 twos there must be a three.  You can take those out of circulation and allocate the rest. $7\choose 4$